# How to create URLs without parameter names in Yii?

Tags: php, url, yii, url-parameters, yii-routing

I'm using the `CGridView` to display a data table:

**`/application/protected/views/foo/bar.php`**

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'my-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        'myid',
        ...
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

That created a table with three links for each row: `view`, `update`, and `delete`; e.g. (for the `view`): `/index.php/foo/123`, where `123` is the ID (or primary key value) of the element.

Now I want to modify the widget call, in order to get different buttons links like `/index.php/bar/123`:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'my-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        'myid',
        ...
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
            'template' => '{view}{update}{delete}',
            'buttons' => array(
                'view' => array(
                    'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("bar", array("myid" => $data->myid))',
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

The (view) link I'm getting looks like this: `/index.php/bar/myid/123` -- and the request ends with a `404` error.

**How to build links without the parameter name in the URL?**

---

Additional info -- my routing configuration in the **`/application/protected/config/main.php`**:

```
return array(
    ...
    'components'=>array(
        ...
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
        ...
    ),
);
```

Comment: The `'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("foo", array("id" => $data->myid))'` generates `/index.php/foo/id/123`, not `/index.php/foo/myid/123`. Are you sure everything in your question is correct?

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Yes, I mistyped. I corrected the question now. Do you have an idea, how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'my-grid',
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filter' => $model,
'columns' => array(
    'myid',
    ...
    array(
        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        'template' => '{view}{update}{delete}',
        'buttons' => array(
            'view' => array(
                'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("bar", array("myId" => $data->myid))',
            )
        ),
    ),
),
));
```

In /protected/config/main.php

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName' => false, 
        'rules'=>array(
                   '<controller:\w+>/<myId:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        ),
    ),
```

Change Action View As

```
    public function actionView($myId){
      $model= User::model()->findByPk($myId);
       $this->render('view' , array('model' => $model));
    }
```

Comment: It's exactly what I tried and what doesn't work: `/index.php/bar/id/1`. I want to pass the `myid` as parameter and get a URL like `/index.php/bar/1`.

Comment: May be Above Code will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

When you have `/index.php/bar/myid/123` as url, the `actionView` of `BarController` must have `myid` (not `id`) as parameter. Probably you have `actionView($id)` and so this cause the problem. So you need to have actionView like this:

```
public function actionView($myid)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's correct. But it's the next step. I've just tried to change the name of the argument in the controller action -- no effect: the generated URL looks then like `/index.php/bar/id/123`. Since it has nothing to do with the URL creation. It's only important on the next step of the URL matching. So I want first to get the URL created.